# Graphic Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

the following code allow me to plot a graph with the data i selected from tw odifferents colum

*definition variables*

```
Dim DerniereLigne_B As Integer
Dim DerniereLigne_C As Integer

'Définition dernière case non vide'
DerniereLigne_B = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
DerniereLigne_C = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Creation graph
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Autoclave cycle"""

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='feuillet 1'!$B$4:$B$" & DerniereLigne_B

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='feuillet 1'!$C$4:$C$" & DerniereLigne_C
```

But i want to make it work what ever sheet i have open. To do so, I create a string variable that is name from my actif sheet

```
Dim nomfeuille As String
nomfeuille = ActiveSheet.Name
```

I want to replace my sheet name by my variable created above

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
     "='feuillet 1'!$B$4:$B$" & DerniereLigne_B
```

I tried it like this

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
      "='nomfeuille'!$B$4:$B$" & DerniereLigne_B
```

But it is not working. How can i write it right to make it work ?

if it can not work do you have idees to make it work. i want to create a graph from the same column variable everytime but with the active sheet.

Comment: Please make sure that posts are in **English** only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
Dim nomfeuille As String

nomfeuille = ActiveSheet.Name

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
            "='" & nomfeuille & "'!$B$4:$B$" & DerniereLigne_B
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need it, I have found how to change the Source Data:
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("H3:H200")